# How to use for loop to save an Excel file into a dictionary?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

here is an Excel file that should be read and saved in several dictionaries, 1 of them is with lists. Other 2 work well but that 'list' one saves nothing. Here is the Excel file look like:

```
woof    jpg js     gif  css png 
0        0  45      0   11  6   
total_time  ip_packets_num  http_packets_num  avg_http_size  packet_num   tcp_packets_num   
76.11243916 395             200               378            1217         395   
srcip           host                     dstip            referer       server      
10.183.195.140  edigitalsurvey.com  108.160.162.38       http://static.bbci.co.uk.css           
                ichef.bbci.co.uk    212.58.244.69        http://static.bbci.co.uk.css           
                notify3.dropbox.com 46.236.9.36          http://static.bbci.co.uk.css           
                sa.bbc.co.uk        77.72.112.168        http://static.bbci.co.uk/.css          
                static.bbci.co.uk   81.23.53.170         http://static.bbci.co.uk.css           
                www.bbc.co.uk       81.23.53.171         http://static.bbci.co.uk.css           
                                                         http://www.bbc.co.uk/
```

The dictionary with lists is saved from 5 line afterwords, it is initialised as:

```
DAlllists={'scrip':[],'dstip':[],'host':[],'referer':[],'server':[]}
```

And the code I am using is:

```
for caption in range(len(DAlllists)):
if Dworksheet.cell_value(4,caption)=='srcip':
    for row in range(len(DAlllists['srcip'])):
        DAlllists['srcip'].append(Dworksheet.cell_value(5+row,caption))
if Dworksheet.cell_value(4,caption)=='dstip':
    for row in range(len(DAlllists['dstip'])):
        DAlllists['dstip'].append(Dworksheet.cell_value(5+row,caption))
if Dworksheet.cell_value(4,caption)=='host':
    for row in range(len(DAlllists['host'])):
        DAlllists['host'].append(Dworksheet.cell_value(5+row,caption))
if Dworksheet.cell_value(4,caption)=='referer':
    for row in range(len(DAlllists['referer'])):
        DAlllists['referer'].append(Dworksheet.cell_value(5+row,caption))
if Dworksheet.cell_value(4,caption)=='server':
    for row in range(len(DAlllists['server'])):
        DAlllists['server'].append(Dworksheet.cell_value(5+row,caption))
```

But the output seems didn't save anything into that dictionary and just give a blank dictionary as it is initialised.
Anyone has any idea to improve the code?

Comment: len(DAlllists['dstip']) is zero so your loops don't run at all. You probably should loop until you get empty cell. Maybe I'll write an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all your code and use this:

```
def read_xc_column(sheet, column, startrow=0):
    row = startrow
    value = sheet.cell_value(row, column)
    answer = []
    while value:
        answer.append(value)
        row = row + 1
        value = sheet.cell_value(row, column)
    return answer

DAlllists = {}
for x in range(5):
   this_col = read_xc_column(Dworksheet, x, 4)
   DAlllists[this_col[0]] = this_col[1:]
```